# Find the index of a partial dictionary element in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have a list of dictionary as follows:

```
myList=[{'id':1,'key1':'a','key2':'b'},{'id':8,'key1':'c','key2':'d'}, 
        {'id':6,'key1':'a','key2':'p'}]
```

To find index of element, I am currently executing following statement:

```
print myList.index({'id':8,'key1':'c','key2':'d'})
```

which returns 1

However, I would like to do something like this:

```
print myList.index({'id':8})
```

should return 1

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need this? It looks like the sort of thing that might merit a rethink of the data structure, though by no means necessarily so.

Comment: @katrielalex: The data-structure I am building is a requirement for another process which requires data to conform to particular standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be relatively simple to implement. Written for Python 3, in Python 2 you should use `.iteritems()` (doesn't create a temporary list).

```
def partial_dict_index(dicts, dict_part):
    for i, current_dict in enumerate(dicts):
        # if this dict has all keys required and the values match
        if all(key in current_dict and current_dict[key] == val 
                for key, val in dict_part.items()):
            return i
    raise ValueError("...")
```

Could use better names though...

Comment: -1 because the line `for i, current_dict in dicts:` results in a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` which has nothing to do with Python 3 vs Python 2 and the use of `iteritems()` (since `dicts` is a `list`, not a dictionary).

Comment: @martineau: I simply forgot the enumerate call. Fixed it.

Comment: OK that's better, I'll remove my down-vote -- you really ought to test code before posting it here. I won't up-vote it however because although it now runs, works, and is short, it still has a potential second degree or quadratic compute time complexity of O(n1xn2) as written, something which could be substantially improved upon.

Comment: @martineau: Come again? I don't see how `all(key in nth_dict for key, _ in dict.items())` has worse complexity than `len(filter(nth_dict.has_key, dict.keys())) == key_count`. In fact, "mine" will stop searching `nth_dict` as soon as soon as there is a key not in `partial`, while "yours" always checks for all keys! Also, I think worst case big O will be (n1 * n2) anyway, since in order to `raise`, we need to see that none of the dicts equals all of `partial` (which is what your code does, too)... or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, you're not mistaken about the performance, I was and aplogize. That said, I now feel your corrected answer is the faster of the two.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a one-liner (as opposed to reusable code), and your data size is small, you could do something like:

```
[elem["id"] for elem in myList].index(8)
```

which extracts the id from each dict, and then finds the index of the provided id. Depending on what your overall goals and data set look like, this might or might not be what you want...

Comment: Well, that was quick one and would solve my problem for this specific solution. Thanx a lot for this one. But, @martineau's answer is more generic and more useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Please change your accepted answer to @delnan's corrected answer which is very similar and likely performs better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this generic solution. Was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement your own list. Here is an example that prints the first found result. I added the ValueError to duplicate the existing behavior of .index().

```
class DictList(list):

    def index(self, obj):
        for i, o in enumerate(self):
            if o['id'] == obj['id']:
                return i
        else:
            raise ValueError('x not in list')


myList = DictList(({'id':1,'key1':'a','key2':'b'},{'id':8,'key1':'c','key2':'d'}, 
                   {'id':6,'key1':'a','key2':'p'}))

>>> print myList.index({'id': 8})
1

>>> print myList.index({'id': 10})
ValueError: x not in list
```

Comment: -1 because the key the `index()` method searches for is hardcoded (to `'id'`) and furthermore it assumes that's the only (key.value) pair in `obj` needing to be matched. IMHO an abstract 'DictList` class would need to have a much more generic and general method.

Comment: There's nothing abstract about it. This is an implementation of list designed to solve the poster's problem in a manner most closely mimicking his desired outcome, not implement all possible uses for a theoretical list of dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps you should then call it something a little less generic than `DictList`. I believe hardcoding values into code is an extremely poor practice, so at the very least even in a non-general routine the key value should be made a class attribute or passed to the `index()` method as keyword argument with a default value. Doing this would allow its value to be changed in a single spot instead of at every occurrences in the existing code.