# Python Find matching item in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a big list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contains timeseries data of each sensor when each data point is collected. I want to know the index location of a specific sensor and date. So, I can update the sensor value.
My code:

```
big_list = [
dict({'sensor':12,'time':'2022-02-03','value':10}),
dict({'sensor':22,'time':'2022-02-03','value':12}),
dict({'sensor':32,'time':'2022-02-03','value':24}),
dict({'sensor':12,'time':'2022-02-04','value':17}),
dict({'sensor':22,'time':'2022-02-04','value':13}),
dict({'sensor':32,'time':'2022-02-04','value':21})]

# Find index of an item 
item_to_find = dict({'time':'2022-02-03','sensor':32})
# solution
big_list.index(item_to_find)
```

Present output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: {'sensor': 32, 'time': '2022-02-03'} is not in list
```

Expected output:

```
2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the index of a partial dictionary element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157400/find-the-index-of-a-partial-dictionary-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this may not be the most efficient solution, but it was the best I could do. :)

```
sensor = 32
time = '2022-02-03'

for item in big_list:
    if item.get('sensor') == sensor and item.get('time') == time:
        print(big_list.index(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `next()` + `enumerate()`:

```py
idx = next(
    i for i, d in enumerate(big_list) if all(d[k] == v for k, v in item_to_find.items())
)
print(idx)
```

Prints:

```
2
```

---

OR: You can add default parameter to `next()` in case the item is not found:

```py
# returns None if the item is not found
idx = next(
    (i for i, d in enumerate(big_list) if all(d[k] == v for k, v in item_to_find.items())), None
)
print(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
list(
    map(
        lambda x: {'time': x['time'], 'sensor': x['sensor']} == item_to_find,
        big_list
    )
).index(True)
```

Explanation:

- use `map()` to extract the values to be compared, stripping away the `value`
- in the function being mapped, make the comparison with `item_to_find` - this will return an iterator which will yield `True` for a match or `False` for a non-match.
- turn the resulting iterator into a list with `list()`
- find the first occurrence in this list of `True` and return the index.

You might also want to look at `pandas` that makes all this a lot more easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as @Andrej but you can use lambda function for clearer intention

```
same_time_and_sensor = lambda item: item['sensor'] == item_to_find['sensor'] and item['time'] == item_to_find['time']

index = next((i for i, item in enumerate(big_list) if same_time_and_sensor(item)), None)

print(index)
```

Here `next()` will return index of the first match or `None` if no match found.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a specific `date` and `sensor` you can make a loop to iterate over every dictionary in the list and save the index of matching item in the list of index:

```
sensor = 32
date = '2022-02-03'

ind = []
for idx, dt in enumerate(big_list):
    if dt['sensor'] == sensor and dt['time'] == date:
        ind.append(idx)

print(ind)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend converting your list of dictionaries to a dataframe. Especially if you need to do this multiple times.

```
import pandas as pd

big_df = pd.DataFrame(big_list).reset_index()
i = big_df[(big_df['sensor']==32)&(big_df['time']=='2022-02-03')]['index'].item()
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found a online answer as well:

```
solution_item = next(filter(lambda s: s['time']==item_to_find['time'] and s['sensor']==item_to_find['sensor'],big_list))

{'sensor': 32, 'time': '2022-02-03', 'value': 24}
```

For index of the solution

```
big_list.index(solution_item)

2
```